QML Array.prototype.includes() doesn't work as expected
I have JS array which stores QModelIndexes
root.selectedIndexes.push(index)
console.log(selectedIndexes)

outputs
[QModelIndex(0,0,0x55e8cb5b5310,TreeModel(0x55e8cb5b2a80))]
if after that check console.log(root.selectedIndexes.includes(index)) outputs false. Why?
however console.log(root.selectedIndexes.indexOf(index)) gives 0
I works as expected with other data types as String or int.
Qt version is 5.12.8

Read the note on QModelIndex documentation page. You should not store it, as it can be invalidated.
